# Can I put LiveShare in a headless mode, e.g. on a shared server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, headless, vscode-liveshare

Today I discovered LiveShare and it seems to fit my use cases for pair programming. Ideally though I'd like to be able to use it on a shared server. Is there a way to do that without running it under X.org? I tried running `lscr.io/linuxserver/code-server:latest` docker container, but I got "500" errors when visiting the marketplace. Is there a supported way of achieving my goal?